# How can I predict the product of the reaction of 2-methyltetrahydrofuran with HI?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

[image: Reaction scheme]

I am supposed to explain why treatment of 2-methyltetrahydrofuran with hydrogen iodide leads to the formation of 5-iodopentan-2-ol. However, I am getting stuck as it seems that the less stable primary carbocation is being preferentially formed, leading to the product. Is my mechanism incorrect?

Comment: The reaction proceeds as either an $\ce {S_{N}1}$ or an $\ce {S_{N}2}$ mechanism. You need to review those mechanisms and determine which mechanism $\ce {I^-}$ would use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, the oxygen in the ring gets protonated. However, there is no formation of a carbocation. The ring opening proceeds by an S<sub>N</sub>2 pathway, where iodide ion attacks at the less hindered carbon:

[image: Mechanism of reaction]